# Understanding Tarski's fixed-point theorem.

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, lattice-orders

I changed my question slightly.

***(Tarski Fixed Point Theorem)***. Let $X=\prod^{N}_{i=1} X_{i}$ where each $X_{i}$ is a compact interval of $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $\phi : X \rightarrow X$ is an increasing function. Then $\phi$ has a fixed point.

I'm not very sure how I should interpret a function being "increasing" when $X\subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Does that mean when we put a two-dimensional vector $x_{1}$ that is elementwise bigger than $x_{2}$, $\phi(x_{1})$ is also elementwise bigger than $\phi(x_{2})$?

Comment: Yes, provided that by "bigger" you mean "greater than or equal".

Comment: Thanks, just one more silly question. In that case,  for instance, whether $\phi(3,2) \geq \phi(4,1)$  or $\phi(3,2) \leq \phi(4,1)$ does not matter at all for the theorem. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, checking whether one of these two inequalities holds  (none that neither of them might hold) is irrelevant when you want to verify that $\phi$ satisfies the assumption of the theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much!